# query on limit of sequence

Tags: limits

> Suppose $a>0$, consider the sequence $a_n=n(\sqrt[n]{ea}-\sqrt[n]{a}), n\geq 1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\text{ ?}$

It is given that limit tends to $1$ but I find it tends to $\infty$. Please explain how it tends to $1$.

Comment: the limit is indeed $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$a_n = \sqrt[n]{a}\cdot n(\sqrt[n]{e}-1).$$

It suffices to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{e}-1) = 1$. If you write $$n(\sqrt[n]{e}-1) = \frac{e^{1/n}-e^0}{\frac 1n},$$ you should see the result.